# Should I mark a question as a duplicate if one answer fits, but the question has a different focus?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, specific-question

I've asked [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42235376/is-it-possible-to-specify-modulus-for-colormaplines) about finding visually distinct colors for plots in Matlab. After asking, I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22029354/3303546) which answers my question very well, however the question that it is an answer on is more general than my question. It simply asks how to plot a number of lines with more than 7 colors, rather than more than 7 visually distinct colors. The only answer that is relevant to me is the one I linked above.

Should I still flag that my question should be marked as a duplicate? I hesitate to do so because the other answers do not address my question.

Comment: What about self-answering your question, instead of marking it as duplicate, with a description of how you solved it (and you can include a reference to that answer if you think it will help other users)